# How do I declare an enum in a cpp class in cython

Tags: c++, enums, cython

I am trying to wrap a c++ library using cython.  The c++ header file say MyFile.h declares a class like this:

```
class MyClass {

public:
    enum MyEnum{
        TYPE0 = 0,
        TYPE1 = 1,
        TYPE2 = 2,   
    };

    MyClass(MyEnum val=TYPE0){
        // ...
    }
    // ...
}
```

The pxd file has this:

```
cdef extern from "<MyFile.h>":

    cdef cppclass MyClass:

        cdef enum MyEnum:
            TYPE0 = 0
            TYPE1 = 1
            TYPE2 = 2

        MyClass(MyEnum val=TYPE0) except +
```

But cython does not compile it.  How do I do this?

Comment: You could start by showing us the compiler error.

Comment: The error is: module.pxd:6:8: Expected an identifier, found 'cdef' Error compiling Cython file:

Answer (score 4):

Try using namespace:

```
cdef extern from "MyFile.h" namespace "MyClass":
    cdef enum MyEnum:
        TYPE0 = 0
        TYPE1 = 1
        TYPE2 = 2
```

Or maybe this will work as well:

```
cdef extern from "MyFile.h":
    cdef enum MyEnum "MyClass::MyEnum":
        TYPE0 = 0
        ...
```

Comment: This is definitely the way to do it. It's probably worth adding that you access this in Python as `MyEnum`, not `MyClass::MyEnum`